# How to publish playlists on facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, timeline, playlist

I'm trying to figure out how to publish "playlist styled" posts on Facebook timeline with list of songs (like Spotify does)? We have web pages representing playlists and the pages marked with "open graph" like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="music.playlist"
<meta property="og:url" content="playlist url">
<meta property="og:title" content="playlist name">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:image" content="image url">
<meta property="music:song" content="song-url-1"
<meta property="music:song" content="song-url-2">
<meta property="music:song" content="song-url-3">
<meta property="music:song" content="song-url-4">
```

However, facebook does not show the list of song. There are just title, description and image appear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a playlist via

```
POST /me/music.playlists
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/music.playlists

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/music.playlist/ the structure of a playlist should be

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# music: http://ogp.me/ns/music#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="302184056577324" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="music.playlist" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Sample Music Playlist" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
  <meta property="music:song:url" content="Sample Song: URL" /> 
</head>
```

Have a look at **music:song:url**, you're using **music:song** only! But I'm not sure if you can create a playlist at all, because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/music.playlists/#requirements states that

> In order to access the Create Playlist action, you must have the appropriate relationships in place with rights owners. We are currently not accepting any new submissions for the Create Playlist action.